# Cancel click on searchbar gives object reference error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I created a custom renderer for searchbar to change its UI. The custom renderer is as below. Issue is when I click n cancel button, it gives an object reference error. Can someone tell me what I should do?

```
[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute(typeof(TransparentSearchBar),typeof(TransparentSearchBarRenderer))]
namespace AmerisureMobile.iOS
{
    public class TransparentSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            UISearchBar bar = this.Control;
            bar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(155, 155, 155, 155);
            bar.SetSearchFieldBackgroundImage(null, UIControlState.Normal);
            bar.AutocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No;
            bar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);
            bar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);
            bar.SearchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal;    
            bar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarPosition.TopAttached, UIBarMetrics.Default);
            bar.SetImageforSearchBarIcon(new UIImage(), UISearchBarIcon.Clear, UIControlState.Disabled);
            UITextField txSearchField = (UITextField)Control.ValueForKey(new Foundation.NSString("searchField"));
            txSearchField.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            txSearchField.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
            txSearchField.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
            txSearchField.Layer.CornerRadius = 2.0f;
            txSearchField.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use the debugger to figure out which element is null

Comment: where to addthe debugger? under which event?

Comment: OnElementChanged, presumably.  That's the code that YOU posted

Comment: OnElementChanged gets called on page load and by that time, we don't have the cancel button on screen, it appears when I type something in the box.

Comment: then why did you even post that code?  If it's crashing, use the stack trace to figure out where the crash occurs, then start debugging there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the method with click event by adding delegate to `searchbar`.

```
//***
bar.Delegate = new MySearchBarDelegate();

class MySearchBarDelegate: UISearchBarDelegate
{
    public override void CancelButtonClicked(UISearchBar searchBar)
    {
        //debug here
    }
}
```